# Angular, router.navigate delayed for the first time after page reload

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried doing a simple `router.navigate()`:

```
navigateToEmployeeView() {
    console.log('DEBUG: NAVIGATE');
    this.loading = true;
    this.router.navigate(['employee']);
  }
```

It works as expected, the only problem being that it takes up to 0.5-1 seconds  after every new page reload till the router changes the URL to the new requested one. The `navigateToEmployeeView()` gets instantly executed, but it does take a bit till it navigates to `.../employee`. It stays on the current URL for a bit till it finally navigates to the new requested one. But that only happens for the first time after every reload. After that the navigation to the new URL happens instantly.

Does anyone have an idea what might delay the first navigation to the new URL after page reload?

Edit:

The route is defined here

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'employee',
    loadChildren: 'app/employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  // more stuff 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: is the route a lazy loaded module, or are there any resolvers on the route. Could you share the config for this route?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when using navigate by URL? this.router.navigateByUrl('/employee');

Comment: i think  you have a problem in your AuthGuard, can you share it's code please

Comment: @c_ogoo Yes, the route is lazyloaded, i shared the code above.


@Mikey123 Yes, i have the same problem if i use your suggested code.

@FatehMohamed That shouldnt be the problem, because the problem still occurs even if i remove the `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` property. In that case, AuthGuard isnt involved at all but the problem still persists.

Comment: issue could be connection speed, since the browser needs to load the module before it can navigate to it

Answer (score 0):

Potentially this isn't an issue, but just some slowness in the connection speed.

Considering the module is lazy loaded, and you only experience the slow-down on a page reload; it may be due to how long it takes for the browser to fetch the lazy loaded module for the first time on your connection. (Check this by looking at the network tab on the browser dev console).

Answer (score 0):

for anyone stumbling upon this in future, i was able to solve this by adding preloadingStrategy in my routing module

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
)
```

ref for more details check angular's [lazy loading documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading)